# What is wrong with my threading python code?

Tags: python, multithreading

Here is my code:

```
   import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time, random
from time import sleep
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from concurrent.futures import Future 
import concurrent.futures
from threading import Thread

def task():
    start_time = time.time()

    with open("url.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            line2 = line.rstrip("\r\n")
            print(line2 + " Hello")
            sleep(1)
            #rechi = requests.get("http://"+line2, verify = False, timeout = 0.5)
            #con = BeautifulSoup(rechi.content, "html.parser")
            #title = con.title
            #print(title)

    print("My program took", time.time() - start_time, "to run")

def main():
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(20)
    future = executor.submit(task)
    print(future.result())

main()
```

The time it takes to execute the program with threading is the same as without threading... Can somebody tell me what am i doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

Multithreading only makes your program faster if you run multiple tasks in parallel.
Your program runs `task` once in a single Thread. Even if you had `task` running multiple times in parallel the time that your program outputs is only the time needed to complete `task` once and not the time needed for the whole program to run.
This prints the time for main and submits `task` multiple times:

```
def main():
   start_time = time.time()
   executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(20)
   futures = []
   futures.append(executor.submit(task))
   futures.append(executor.submit(task))
   for i in futures:
       print(i.result())
   print("main took {} seconds".format(time.time()-start_time))
```

Comment: I understand... how can i run task() multiple times in parallel? what should i add to my code?